# What is the source of vacuum energy during the inflationary era?

Tags: quantum-field-theory, cosmology, cosmological-inflation, cosmological-constant

It is assumed that during the *inflationary epoch* the universe is dominated by the *vacuum energy*. What is the source of this vacuum energy and how it that related to the energy of the inflaton field?

Comment: Why does it need a "source"?

Comment: Something must contribute to the vacuum energy. Right? May be the inflaton field itself.

Comment: Energy is not conserved in cosmology. I mean, it may well be that something *is* "contributing" to it, but I do not see a reason why something *must* contribute to it.

Comment: Not right. Vacuum energy (dark energy, cosmological constant) dominated epoch is right now. During the inflation, inflaton field(s) with appropriate potential was dominating the universe.

Comment: The old inflation assumed that the universe was in false vacuum during inflation. But now, favoured inflationary potentials are plateau-like (with small slope) during that period.

Answer (score 4):

The general idea is that during the inflationary epoch there was a scalar field permeating through space that had a very large potential energy density. Configurations of field (like the electromagnetic field) can have both kinetic and potential energy associated with them.

If such a field had a very high potential energy density associated with it, for example, because the field had a nonzero (vacuum expectation) value everywhere in space that would have a lot of potential energy associated with it, most of the energy of the field would be carried by its potential energy, and not by its kinetic energy density. Since the energy density of a field is proportional to 
$$
T^\mu_{\;\;\nu} = \frac{\partial \mathcal{L}}{\partial(\partial_\mu \phi)} \partial_\nu \phi - \mathcal{L}\delta^\mu_{\;\;\nu}
$$
where $\mathcal{L} \sim P - V $ is the Lagrangian density of the field (which is proportional to its potential energy density minus its kinetic energy density), we see that if the potential energy density of the field is much larger than the field's kinetic energy density, the resulting energy-momentum tensor will behave like a negative energy density.

In most models, people tune the dynamics of the inflation field in such a way that as the universe rapidly expands, this field slowly loses its potential energy and the expansion process comes to a halt. There is no precise relation between the amount of potential energy stored in the inflation field at the beginning of the expansion process and some sort of energy that will be stored in the spacetime afterward. Part of the reason is that in an expanding universe we can no longer define a notion of 'globally conserved energy', but that is another topic.

How the inflationary field got into this particular configuration and how this potential energy got 'stored' in the inflation field in the first place, is usually not addressed. We don't know that happened before the inflationary epoch or how the universe behaves at even higher energies, the main focus is on trying to derive a model (withing the modern framework of (quantum) field theory) that answers several questions in cosmology (like the horizon and flatness problems) and give at the same time an accurate prediction of e.g. the distribution of hot and cold spots on the CMB background. Inflation is a general framework that describes how this could have happened using field theory, but of course, we can always ask 'what happened before that' or 'where did this field come from'. Perhaps in the future, it will turn out that the 'inflation field' is only an effective description of an even bigger overarching theoretical framework? Untill then we don't know and people try to come up with the simplest model that best fits the available data.

Answer (score 2):

I have addressed your question in three parts:

> It is assumed that during the inflationary epoch the universe is dominated by the vacuum energy.

During the inflationary epoch, the expansion of the universe was dominated by the inflaton field, which is different from the vacuum energy which currently dominates expansion.

> how it that related to the energy of the inflaton field?

Both vacuum energy and and the inflaton field dominated universes give rise to accelerating expansion but have important differences (see [Quintessence](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quintessence_(physics))). For a over-simplified rudimentary intuition about the energy conservation aspect, one can say that the field loses it's energy which is then used by the universe to expand but it must be kept in mind that this is an oversimplification.

> What is the source of this vacuum energy

According to Wikipedia:

> Vacuum energy is an underlying background energy that exists in space throughout the entire Universe.

the reason why the vacuum has a non-zero energy contrary to what one expects can be basically attributed to the Heisenberg Uncertainty principle which forbids us from knowing the *exact* state of any field.

For a rudimentary intuition about the energy conservation aspect, one can say that the field loses it's energy which is then used by the universe to expand but it must be kept in mind that this is quite an oversimplification of the complex underlying theory *which is still not yet fully understood* .

As for the origins of the inflaton field and why things were in the state they were, as JgL pointed out in his excellent in-depth answer, that is still an open question.

Comment: In the case of inflation, the (negative) energy density that drives the inflationary epoch is in general due to the potential energy density of the 'inflaton field', this is a statement about classical field theory and there is no need to quantize these fields. You mention several times in your answer that a quantum mechanical vacuum has a nonzero vacuum energy, but these vacuum fluctuations don't have anything to do with why the universe expands in theories of inflation. Inflation describes a classical spacetime that expands due to the energy density of a classical field in this spacetime.

Comment: Yes, I have made it clear in the first part itself that the vacuum energy isn't the cause for inflation. the further comments regarding vacuum energy were to address the OP's confusion about  "what is the source of vacuum energy"

Comment: OP is asking for the source of the 'vacuum energy' that dominates the universe during the inflationary epoch. This is due to the vacuum expectation value of the field and its associated potential energy, not the 'vacuum fluctuations' that are caused by the kinetic terms in the Lagrangian (after quantizing the theory). It is confusing terminology that both are called 'vacuum energy', but the former is a classical effect (that is the relevant 'vacuum energy' here), the second is a quantum effect that in inflationary models is small compared to the (classical) potential energy and can be ignored.

Comment: After my discussion with you, my own question is all of a sudden downvoted by someone without giving any explanation. I'll suppose that's just coincidence?

Comment: @JgL this probably belongs in a personal message but since I don't know how to do that I'll reply here. First of all I wasn't aware that my reply seemed hostile to you in the first place fr you to think that I would do such a pointless thing. If you want proof tell me which question and I can upvote it temporarily, if you see an increase of 5 points then you know it wasn't me.

Comment: I think you both had some pretty good explanations, and agree with Jagl that that the two, inflaton and dark energy are not the same physics. At least we have some plausible models for the inflaton, but dark energy I'm not so sure of. Anyway, both up voted. Btw, it was not me either.

Comment: @alex, my apologies, I guess you are right about me being inappropriate. I had gotten a little annoyed and triggered after some people took some of my comments on their posts rather personal and considered them to be hostile. I unjustly assumed this would be the case with almost every discussion in the comment section, but it is nice to see there are still some reasonable people around. My apologies again, I will do my best to not make assumptions again that fast in the future.